# How to iterate one property over more than one JSON Arrays in response array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have response array like below comes fromm `HTTP Get` Request

[image]

I want to print all these name properties of any object using `*ngFor`.Here I tried below but didn't work.

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let index of filteredNames">
              <h4>{{index.name}}</h4>
      </ng-container>
```

FilteredNames have objects as you can see on the image taken by console

Comment: I don't know angular, but in docs I see they don't have `;` https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

Comment: Im sorry for that.I put there accidentally while I was editing that code

Comment: you have array of array. You should probably flatten it. please post sample of you data

Comment: I know I need to flat but how.I tried some JSON methods but didn't work.

Comment: [array flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/flat) will do the job.

Comment: @Yanis-git thanks very much.It worked.I didnt know javascript has this method.In typescript it means [ ].concat(...arrayName)

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on how you want to show it in the view.

You have an array of arrays. If you want to loop through all values in the second array, you could have:

```html
<div *ngFor="let filteredName of filteredNames">
  <!-- this will show all the values in the second array -->
  <div *ngFor="let value of filteredName">{{ value.name }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.This is also goodway.But make array flatten is best I think because using two for loops bring more cost.

Comment: Are both arrays containing the same data shape?

Answer (score 0):

here is the same example look into. hope it will help you.

I have give flatten example using js in angular.

In component

```
filteredNames = [];
    ArrayFromBackResponse = [
        [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: "test",
            hospitalId: 2
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: "test2",
            hospitalId: 2
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            id: 9,
            name: "test25",
            hospitalId: 2
          }
        ]
      ];
    constructor() {
        this.filteredNames = [].concat.apply([],this.ArrayFromBackResponse);
     }
```

In html

```
<p *ngFor="let o of filteredNames">
  {{o.name}}
</p>
```

we can also flatten array using lodash(_ underscore.js) lib..

```
filteredNames = _.flatten(this.ArrayFromBackResponse);
```

Thanks,

kushal